# site URL for Watin in TFS Build

Tags: url, build, tfs, watin

I have set up a TFS 2010 build server and it is working well.  I would now like to introduce some UI tests using Watin.  How can this be set up?

Clearly the tests happen after the build, and have to be against that build, but I don't see any option to mount the built code in IIS to use for the tests.  How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to deploy the compiled site to a web server. Msdeploy is good for this.

In my BuildProcessTemplate I first package the web site as MsBuild task

CommandLingArguments:

```
String.Format("/T:Package /p:DeployOnBuild=False 
    /p:PackageLocation=_PublishedWebsites\YourApp\{0}.zip 
    /p:DeployIisAppPath=YourApp.com/{1}", EnvironmentName, EnvironmentName)
```

(specifying your web project in release mode)

The next task is an InvokeProcess with the following file name

```
SourcesDirectory + "\YourApp\_PublishedWebsites\YourApp\" 
    + EnvironmentName + ".deploy.cmd"
```

Details will differ but I think you get the idea.  There are a few other challenges to getting WatiN running all tests.  We can come back to that, probably a broader question.

Comment: How are you managing to write code against the CommandLineArguments for MSBuild? As far as I can see, it only takes a string?

Comment: in your build process template viewer, right click on a msbuild task and you'll see various properties, one of which is CommandLineArguments

Comment: Got you. Not sure what limits of code are but string format and global variables as you can see are fine. You should get intellisense too

Comment: Hmm, no, it's just a bare textbox for me.  Certainly no intellisense.

This is what I have:
/p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:MsDeployPublishMethod=InProc /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:DeployIisAppPath="My Test Site" /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=myservername

but the deployment package is not created and nothing is deployed. There are no errors shown so I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

(After deploying your code to IIS)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728093.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334

WatiN works great running from mstest combined with an interactive desktop. A great way to provide interactive desktop for remote machines are with the test controller and test agents.

Comment: It's the deploying to IIS that I don't know how to get working.